# Karma unit test tries to send a request to a completely different module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, angular-fullstack

I have the following karma test for the angular-fullstack scaffold:

```
describe('Directive: categoryLookAhead', function () {

  // load the directive's module and view
  beforeEach(module('portfolioApp'));
  beforeEach(module('app/article/Directives/categoryLookAhead/categoryLookAhead.html'));

  var element, scope;

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  it('should make hidden element visible', inject(function ($compile) {
    element = angular.element('<category-look-ahead></category-look-ahead>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$apply();
    expect(element.text()).not.toBe(null);
  }));
});
```

and this is my karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
    basePath: '',

    // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'client/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
      'client/bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.compat.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-socket-io/socket.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-markdown/angular.markdown.js',
      'client/bower_components/angular-ui-router-title/angular-ui-router-title.js',
      'client/app/app.js',
      'client/app/app.coffee',
      'client/app/**/*.js',
      'client/app/**/*.coffee',
      'client/components/**/*.js',
      'client/components/**/*.coffee',
      'client/app/**/*.jade',
      'client/components/**/*.jade',
      'client/app/**/*.html',
      'client/components/**/*.html'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.jade': 'ng-jade2js',
      '**/*.html': 'html2js',
      '**/*.coffee': 'coffee',
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'client/'
    },

    ngJade2JsPreprocessor: {
      stripPrefix: 'client/'
    },

    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [],

    // web server port
    port: 8080,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: false,


    // Start these browsers, currently available:
    // - Chrome
    // - ChromeCanary
    // - Firefox
    // - Opera
    // - Safari (only Mac)
    // - PhantomJS
    // - IE (only Windows)
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

and this is the directive's controller:

```
angular.module('portfolioApp')
  .directive('categoryLookAhead', function($interval, $filter) {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/article/Directives/categoryLookAhead/categoryLookAhead.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        suggestedTags: '=',
        selectedTags: '='
      },
...
```

In my head, it should just compile from that template and start doing its thing but I get an error:

`Error: Unexpected request: GET app/main/main.html`

main.html does not include this directive at all, so I don't know why it's getting an unexpected request for this.

I've read in other StackOverflow posts that I can use whenGET(*).passThrough() to ignore these things, but I'd like to know why it's making a request to a module that has nothing to do with the directive.

Comment: If the template uses `ng-include` or the `.run` method (or anything, really) requests this template you will have this problem.

Comment: Did a quick check on the view and controller and doesn't have ng-include or .run. I am including the entire app with `beforeEach(module('portfolioApp'));` so wondering if that's affecting it?

Comment: I mean that `ng-include` or `.run` can be *anywhere* in `portfolioApp`.  It seems like when the module is initialized, `app/main/main.html` is loaded by Angular somewhere.  Are you doing any kind of routing?

Comment: If this is working well and it is failing just in the test maybe you should post your karma config file.

Comment: Oh, I see. I'm using ng-include in pretty much all of my views for footer and navbar. and i have a .run in my client/app/app.js. I'll update with my karma.conf.js